# How to change routerLink in Angular and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, angular13

I have some menus in the header. Now I want to add query string parameters to all header menus programmatically. My code is like this.

```
<nav class="menu-links">
    <ul class="postlogin">        
        <li><a routerLink="/passenger/home" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/passenger/myride" routerLinkActive="active">My Ride</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/passenger/profile" routerLinkActive="active">Profile</a></li>       
    </ul> </nav>
```

My final code will be like this:

```
<nav class="menu-links">
        <ul class="postlogin">        
            <li><a routerLink="/passenger/home?pi=160016" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a routerLink="/passenger/myride?pi=160016" routerLinkActive="active">My Ride</a></li>
            <li><a routerLink="/passenger/profile?pi=160016" routerLinkActive="active">Profile</a></li>       
        </ul> </nav>
```

I want to do this from ngOnInit method of a page.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    //add query string to all the header menu
}
```

I am using Angular 13, and typescript.

I did that in a jQuery project like this:

```
 $('a[class="aff-menu-item"]').each(function () {
        var oldUrl = $(this).attr("href");
        var newUrl = oldUrl + "?pi=160016";
        $(this).attr("href", newUrl);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transfer parameter from child component to parent component or you can transfer parameter from parent component to child component.

Best way is crate a service and transfer parameter by using this service.

Service code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class QueryStringService {

  constructor() { }

  message: string = "";

  setQueryString(data) {
    this.message = data;
  }

  getQueryString() {
    return this.message;
  }
}
```

Child component code:

```
ngOnInit(): void {    
    this.queryStringService.setQueryString(Id);
    
  }
```

Menu component code:

```
queryString: string = "";
  constructor(
    private queryStringService: QueryStringService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.queryString = this.queryStringService.getQueryString();    
  }


 <li><a routerLink="/passenger/home" [queryParams]="{pi
                                        :queryString }" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/passenger/myride" [queryParams]="{pi
                                        :queryString }" routerLinkActive="active">My Ride</a>
        </li>
        <li><a routerLink="/passenger/profile" [queryParams]="{pi
                                        :queryString }" routerLinkActive="active">Profile</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [Angular doc](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-or-interpolation), you can use property binding:

HTML code:

```html
<nav class="menu-links">
        <ul class="postlogin">        
            <li><a [routerLink]="'/passenger/home' + query"  routerLinkActive="active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a [routerLink]="'/passenger/myride' + query" routerLinkActive="active">My Ride</a></li>
            <li><a [routerLink]="'/passenger/profile' + query" routerLinkActive="active">Profile</a></li>       
        </ul> </nav>
```

TS code:

```
query:string="";

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.query="?pi=160016";
  }
```

Comment: Your code is not working. I want to add query string from one component to all router link.